# How do I debug a situation where Elmah is not logging errors on host but is locally?

Tags: c#, deployment, elmah

So I have a situation where locally, Elmah is working correctly.  When I generate exceptions, Elmah is correctly logging them.

However, after deploying the system out to my GoDaddy system, Elmah doesn't seem to work.  I can load the `Elmah.axd` site correctly with no errors (it shows nothing though), but when I trigger exceptions, no error xml files are actually logged.  How can I go about debugging this, since Elmah doesn't seem to be throwing any exceptions?

For reference, my Elmah config is:

```
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
  </elmah>
```

Comment: I'm having Elmah log to `xml` though, not to a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the permissions on appdata folder...it needs to have read and write permission...
i would create a separate folder instead of using appdata. Assign the user account to that folder with full permission.

Comment: Aha that was it.  Visual Studio deployment wasn't giving the directory write permission